# Is there any tutorial on English to French translation in CNTK

Tags: cntk

I have found the article describing the experience https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Sequence-to-Sequence-%E2%80%93-Deep-Recurrent-Neural-Networks-in-CNTK-%E2%80%93-Part-2. But I am looking for the code as to understand better. I can see the author of the article is William Darling and would like to know if he can publish the code in examples or tutorials.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial, with lots of explanations:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb